# How to stop only the last fetch request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch

So I'm trying to fetch some photos from a website to create gallery.
The thing is when I want to **sort by author** I empty my photos[] to repopulate it within the fetch.

```
sortByAuthor() {
    console.log('Sort')
    this.setPhotos([]); //Emptying
    this.fetchGallery();
},
fetchGallery() {
    const url = new URL('wtv');
    const params = {
        author: this.sortByAuthor ? this.sortByAuthor : '',
        order: this.sortByDate,
        limit: this.limit
    };
    url.search = new URLSearchParams(params);

    fetch( url , {
        method: 'GET',
    }).then((response) => {

        response.json().then((data) => {
            this.fetchGallery(this.photos.length)
        });
    }).catch();
}
```

[image]

How would you do to only cancel the last fecth ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto well I've tried to use controller.abort() but I don't know where to put this since It actually cancel too my `good`fetch

Comment: I don't understand why your fetchGallery calls itself again after the fetch `this.fetchGallery(this.photos.length)`